# How to delete a particular row,with out any Where condition, in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code

```
<?php

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        { 
            //Do some process

            //Then delete this row 
        }
```

I need to delete each row  within the while loop.

is it possible?there is no primary key for this table

Comment: why dont just DELETE FROM table_name ??

Comment: Why not a simple `DELETE FROM table` if you need to delete every row?

Comment: You will need some kind of key or reference to delete the needed rows, unless you want to delete the entire data set.

Comment: Not a bad question, upvoting to offset.

Comment: @Passerby he also wants to process the record first.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Still be able to `TRUNCATE`, just need to run outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, MySQL would have no clue on which record to delete.

You either use the primary key, or you add all fields and add a `LIMIT`, and even then you have no way of knowing for sure it is that row.

If you want to delete all records from a table, use

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table1
```

So, if you are **actually** doing `SELECT * FROM table1`, I'd code it as such:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    //Do some process

}
mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE table1");
```

(of course, don't use the `mysql_*` functions, but MySQLi or PDO)

Answer (score 1):

> [Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php) They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli) - this [article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.

You could use the following MySQLI code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
$result= $mysqli -> query($query);

while($row = $result -> fetch_object()){

      $row_identifier = $row -> column_with_unique_id;

      // Do the processing bit here.

      // Now Delete
      $del_query = "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE column_with_unique_id = ".$row_identifier;
      $del_result= $mysqli -> query($del_query);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

From your code it looks like you wish to delete *all* entries from the table. (Because that's what your code/pseudocode does.) You can do that much easier with:

```
 DELETE FROM table
```

And please don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore. They are marked as deprecated and will eventually be removed from PHP. Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead.

Comment: Faster even with `TRUNCATE TABLE`